# Как прокрутить экран к объекту чтобы он находился по центру?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как прокрутить экран к объекту чтобы он находился по центру ? А также как отключить анимацию скроллинга ?

```
  var icon = document.querySelector('.next_h'),
    content = document.querySelector('.match');
icon.onclick = function () {
  scrollTo(800, content.offsetTop);
}

function scrollTo(duration, position) {
  var beginPosition = 0,
    step = duration / position,
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
      if (beginPosition <= position) {
        window.scroll(0, beginPosition);
        beginPosition += 1;
      } else clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }, step);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому вопросу: нужно в функцию отправлять позицию элемента вычитая из нее половину высоты экрана, а если еще чтоб элемент совсем был по центру то нужно добавить половину высоты самого элемента!

Например: `content.offsetTop - window.innerHeight / 2 + content.clientHeight / 2`

По второму вопросу, тут неправильно построена функция, т.к. функция setInterval не может повторяться чаще чем в 4мс и если у нас к примеру до элемента 1200px то функция будет повторяться 1200 раз. *1200 * 4 ~ 5 сек.*
Поэтому нужно установить задержку в `setInterval(..., 1)`, а  шаг переделать в количество пикселей добавляемых каждые 4 мс.

```
  step = position / duration;
  beginPosition += step;
```

Тогда, если мы поставим duration 1, у нас не будет анимации т.к. значение сразу встанет в первые 4 мс.
Чтоб избежать ошибки, добавим проверку duration на 0 и ниже.

```
if(duration <= 0) duration = 1;
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/9kmtj6e4/